# How to send image as attachment using Mandrill API in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, mandrill

I am integrating **Mandrill** API to send emails from iOS. I m unable to send image as attachment with email. I am using **api/1.0/messages/send.json** with proper images JSON described in their [doc](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html). I have encode image to base64 string as well but when I send it I just get email without attachment.

Comment: Have resolved it @Ahad Khan